# How to make Vertical slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to do a slidedown and up with the mouse while holding like a touch screen or a scrollbar. But the problem is that I need to be able to do that while clicking on it and moving the mouse and still be able to click the things that are under it like links a stuff, since its not images.
I can't find anything.Can someone tell me about any jquery plugin or css trick or something like that?

Comment: This is really quite confusing. If you clarify, chances are much better to find an answer.

Comment: just think of what a scroll bar does. basicly i want that fuction but with out a bar just click and drag down like the swipe you do on a touch mobile just as simple as that . With the Up and down direction

Comment: So you want to navigate full screen sections of a web page by using swipe or something similar? And for that swiping to not trigger links that may be on that page. That's a job for touch events, they can be separated from clicks. Doable but not with a simple trick, only some solid coding. Here's the closest and least complicated example I have at hand : http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/RNRGaa?editors=001.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... so it sounds like you want to scroll a website while the mouse button is held down. This will need some work to be useful in a practical scenario. It causes items to be selected, it does not account for momentum, and so forth.

This is the result of three events:

**'mousemove'**: Keeps track of current mouse position (vertically) at all times, even when the mouse button is not pressed. This means that the event is continually fired at all times, whenever you move your mouse, but all it does is change a single variable so the performance loss is minimal. You could micromanage adding and removing the event, but that's a headache (especially if you want to track the mouse for more than one thing).

**'mousedown'**: Sets a flag to declare that scrolling has started, notes where the mouse is *now*, and queues an animation for the *next* frame to do something about it.

**'mouseup'**: Removes the flag set by the mousedown event, such that the *next* frame of animation is the last one for this batch of scrolling.

Both `scrollStart()` and `scrollStop()` will fire regardless of left or right mouse button being fired. You can change them to `scrollStart(e)` and `scrollStop(e)`. You can then check `e.button` in each function to see whether it's left, right, or scroll wheel, which returns `0`, `2`, and `1` respectively.

Outside of those three events, it is just animation logic. Every frame, see how far the mouse moved and add that offset (+ or -) to the document's current scroll position.

`documentScrollTop()` gets the document's current scroll position. Thanks to TheMikeRoss for the cross-browser polyfill.

`window.scrollTo(left, top)` actually performs the scroll.

```
// ScrollTop polyfill from TheMikeRoss
// Lets you know how much 
function documentScrollTop() {
  "use strict";
  return (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop
  === document.documentElement.scrollTop) ?
      document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
};

function scrollStart() {
  "use strict";
  window.bIsScrolling = true;
  window.lastMousePosition = window.mousePosition;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawScroll);
};

function scrollStop() {
  "use strict";
  window.bIsScrolling = false;
};

function scrollOnMove(e) {
  "use strict";
  window.mousePosition = e.clientY;
};

function drawScroll() {
  "use strict";
  var scrollDistance,
    scrollLocation;

  if (window.bIsScrolling) {
    //Mouse still held down, keep scrolling
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawScroll);
  }

  scrollDistance = window.lastMousePosition - window.mousePosition;
  scrollLocation = window.documentScrollTop() + scrollDistance;
  window.scrollTo(0, scrollLocation);
  window.lastMousePosition = window.mousePosition;
};

window.addEventListener('mousedown', scrollStart, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', scrollStop, false);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', scrollOnMove, false);
```